# How do I control the rate of the audio ScriptProcessor function

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, scriptprocessor

Here's my basic example, I couldn't put it in a snippet as it generate a security error.
The problem is the processing rate is a little bit high, compared to my needs which is about 300 to 500 milliseconds between each. is there a way to control it.
And is there a way to pause the processing, until the microphone receives a input.
Thank you for your help.

html out that shows the rate:

> `<input type='text' id='output' >`

the script:`

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    },
    function(stream) {
        output=document.getElementById("output");
        audioContext = new AudioContext();  
 
      
      analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
      microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      javascriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(256, 1, 1);

      analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;// 0.8;
      analyser.fftSize = 32;//1024;
 
      microphone.connect(analyser);
      analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
      javascriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

      canvasContext = document.querySelector("#canvas").getContext("2d");

      javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
          var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
          analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
          var values = 0;

          var length = array.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values += (array[i]);
          }

          var average = values / length;
          
          output.value= average;
         

        } // end fn stream
 
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name)
    });
} else {
  console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

What I'm trying to do is really simple. All I need is to scroll the page by a bit whenever the the audio volume pass a threshold, if you have a simpler alternative, It would be even better. Like how to access the volume in a setTimeout callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your `ScriptProcessorNode` with a buffer size of 256.  That means the `onaudioprocess` event gets call every 256 frames, which is about every 5 ms (at 44.1 kHz).  If you want something on the order of 300 ms, use `0.3 * 44100` or 16384 since the buffer size is a power of two.

Note also that you don't need to call the analyser node to get the data.  The `onaudioprocess` function already has the data passed in in the event, which you don't use.

Also, depending on your use case, you could get rid of the script processor altogether and just use the analyser node to get the data you want.  But then you'll need a `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` to periodically request data from the analyser node.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I think using a setTimeout would do the trick. Though, is there a way to pause everything until the mic received an initial sound.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with mic input.   You might have to do that yourself.